# Is it possible to find the "referring/parent object(s)" when serializing?

Tags: java, serialization

We are using an OODBMS, which allows both Java "entities" and serialized objects too. The DB supports true graphs (no "tree" restriction) and serialized objects can safely reference entities as well. The DB works (almost) transparently, and we can do whatever we want, and it-just-works.

Now, I've discovered that objects that had been marked as "logically deleted" (using a simple boolean flag, rather then built-in DB functionality, since the DB doesn't have such a concept) are loaded/saved within a particular object graph.

I want to know which object(s) references those "zombie" objects. Trying to use reflection to iterate over the graph has not worked so far. Instead of the DB, I can simply use Java serialization to export the object graph, and this also causes the "zombie" objects to be serialized.

My question is: can I somehow extract the information about the object(s) that is holding a reference to a "zombie" object during the serialisation process (the "parent" object)? There can be more then one, but as long as I have one, I can work iteratively until I killed off all those invalid references.

Comment: Which OODBMS specifically are you using? And which version?

Comment: The very reason why we have introduced a "logically deleted" flag, is because the DB does not offer a way to find "parent" objects, and therefore also offers no "GC" for the entities. The long term goal is to verify that all objects marked as logically deleted are truly unreferenced, so we can eventually delete them.

Answer (score 1):

Most OODBMS allow to run queries which return object references that satisfy certain constraints. So you could write something like this:

```
return all objects
where deleted == true
and Foo.bar == this
```

where `Foo` is the type of the object which references the deleted objects and `bar` is the field/property that contains the reference.

The exact syntax depends on your OODBMS.

Comment: Indeed, *most* do, but not ours (which is one more reason not to mention the product by name; I'm not trying to do them bad publicity), so it's not a solution for us. Also, it would only work for "direct" references by entities, not for references hidden in serialized objects.

Comment: In that case, you need to live with the way things are or give me more information. Note: If the DB can serialize a reference, then it's not "hidden". If it can serialize the reference, then it can also query it somehow. Without this, the DB couldn't even load children.

Comment: To put it simply, the DB server is the one that runs the queries, but for the server, serialized object are just byte arrays. The actual (de-)serialisation of the serialized objects happens on the client, which means many server calls can be needed to fully load a large object graph, but this is all transparent to us. It also means that the server isn't aware of references to entities from within those byte arrays. The DB uses a unified ID space for entities (64-bit long), and replace the entity references with "handles" during serialisation. We cannot modify the Handle class.

Comment: In that case, my solution would be a second DB server which wraps the original one and which offers a "high level" API. On that server, you should be able to create indexes for serialized references so you can keep a list of where they are used.